# How to Filter category data without change URL and querystring in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new in bigcommerce and I using the stencil and bigcommerce/stencil-utils.

When I filter data from provided option then add query string with existing URL as per below URL.

[https://gemsnytest.mybigcommerce.com/loose-gemstones/?_bc_fsnf=1&carat[]=0.46&carat[]=3](https://gemsnytest.mybigcommerce.com/loose-gemstones/?_bc_fsnf=1&carat%5B%5D=0.46&carat%5B%5D=3)

After then data filter.

Any possible way to product data filter data without add query string in URL in bigcommerce

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not natively possible with Cornerstone and you would have to build this out yourself.

One option would be to create & inject custom scripts on custom catalog templates that can handle the filtering with JS, compared to how BigCommerce natively handles this, with query strings. The method BigCommerce is using with query strings could be useful from a merchandising/marketing perspective as you can link to your filtered results as its own page so that's something to consider when thinking of alternatives without present in the url.

Depending on the priority, size and flexibility needed for this requirement and where you are in your site building process, you could also consider building out a headless storefront. You could use the [GraphQL](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-overview) API to query catalog results, or our [S2S](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/catalog/catalog-overview) APIs. To handle the filtering, you could look at storing this in the state (if you were to build a storefront with a state management library) or something custom to your liking that can handle the filtering in a more discrete way.